# Find the position and the value of the first positive element and of the last negative element in the C language

Tags: c, arrays

I have a one-dimensional array in the C language. I enter the number of elements (n) and then I enter the elements themselves. I want to find the position and the value of the first positive element and of the last negative element. How can I do it? I was thinking about something like this, but there's a semantic error and I'm stuck. I am just a beginner and I would really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int Array[100], i, n;

    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter %d elements\n", n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter number%d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &Array[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (Array[i] > 0)
        {
            printf("The first positive element is %d\n", Array[i]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 100; i < n; i--)
    {
        if (Array[i] < 0)
        {
            printf("The last negative element is %d\n", Array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post _'there is an error'_ without posting the full text of that error.

Comment: You forgot `break;` inside `if (Array[i]>0)` after print statement.

Comment: @underscore_d I'm sorry. By saying there's a semantic error I meant that the program runs successfully, but it does not do the right thing.

Comment: @GauravPathak Thank you!

Comment: So your post should include clear descriptions of what you expected, versus what really happened.

Comment: You always run the second loop starting from 100, `for (i=100; i<n; i--)` what if you haven't entered 100 elements. What's gonna happen if you have entered only 5 or 10 elements?

Comment: @GauravPathak The `<` vs `--` there don't make any sense, anyway.

Comment: @underscore_d Right! :-D

Comment: Reading `Array[100]` is undefined behaviour. In fact there' possible undefined behaviour for any `n` value because you might be accessing uninitialized locations in `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

Test for first positive does not exit so you'll get all of them.

Test for negative needs to start at n-1 not 100 and terminate after it has tested element 0. It, too, needs to break when it's found one.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
 for (i=100; i<n; i--)
```

you should write

```
for (i=(n-1); i>=0; i--)
```

that way you start from the last inserted element until you reach 0, the beggining of your array. 
Furthermore in your if's you could use a break; command after your printf's. That way when you meet an element with the required characteristics you exit your loop. If you don't use break, you print every positive and negative element, not just the first you meet

Comment: Needs to be n-1. 10 elements are 0 to 9

Comment: @LoztInSpace Writing `for (i = n; i--;)` would solve that. Note that the postdecrement is in the 2nd clause, not the 3rd. I'm sure some readers don't like that syntax, but it's second nature to me. (Also, my usual _'please stop using postinc/decrement by default/where not needed._')

Answer (score 1):

Few problems:

1. in your 2nd loop - you don't `break`, meaning it will continue running (and printing!!) even after 1st positive was found
2. in your 3rd loop - `i = 100; i < n`. Wrong! it should have been `i = n-1; i >= 0` since the array is only 100 elements long. And also the same problem with no `break` as before
3. **INDENTATION!!!!** (makes your code readable)
4. What happens if `n > 100` ? (hint: you will insert elements to memory you don't own --> **UB**)

---

Here is a fixed version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int Array[100], i, n;
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if( n > 100)
    {
         printf("error\n");
         return 1;
    }
    printf("Enter %d elements\n", n);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter number%d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d", &Array[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (Array[i]>0)
        {   
            printf("The first positive element is %d\n", Array[i]);
            break;
        }
    }

    for (i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if (Array[i]<0)
        {  
            printf("The first negative element is %d\n", Array[i]); 
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It needs to be n-1 not 99 specifically. Range checking is also a factor